# Updating bash environment variables using source

Tags: command-line, path, terminal, environment-variables, osx-mountain-lion

On `OS X Mountain Lion` The `source` command only seems to update my path when I have *added* something to it in .bashrc or .bash_profile. If I *delete* a path from either of these files, then use `source` to update, the deleted path remains. An example...

Adding to my `PATH` in `.bash_profile`

In `terminal`

```
> echo $PATH
> "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin"
```

Add to path in `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop
```

Back in `terminal`

```
> source .bash_profile
> echo $PATH
> "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/myname/Desktop"
```

So, all that went as expected; my `Desktop` has been added to my `PATH`. Now after I delete the previously added path from `.bash_profile`, leaving this file empty

```
> source .bash_profile
> echo $PATH
> "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/myname/Desktop"
```

As you can see the 'deleted' path `'/Users/myname/Desktop'` remains. Am I misunderstanding what
`source` does? I thought It was equivalent to opening a new terminal window (which does return
the result I was expecting - i.e. no Desktop path)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `source .bash_profile` first time, because of `export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop` line from `.bash_profile` file, your PATH is reassigned to old PATH to which is added `~/Desktop` directory.

When you use `source .bash_profile` second time, the PATH is not anymore reassigned because you delete `export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop` line. So, this time the value of your PATH remains unchanged (like before).

You have to restart your terminal (current shell) if you want that the value of your PATH to return to its initial value. Or you can source your `/etc/environment` file:

```
source /etc/environment
```